# Display only certain list items in listview with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a listview with the help of jquery mobile and it's currently displaying 4 list items. The list is generated with javascript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var data = [{
        "name": "Lichtbediening",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
        "img": "lichtbediening"
}, {
        "name": "Stopcontact",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor stopcontacten",
        "img": "stopcontacten"
}, {
        "name": "Enkele schakelaar",
        "info": "Een knop, een lamp",
        "img": "rolluikbediening"       
}, {
        "name": "Dubbele schakelaar",
        "info": "Twee knoppen, twee lampen",
        "img": "multimedia"     
}];

var output = '';
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    output += '<li><a href="#">'
    output += '<img src="img/' + value.img + '.jpg">'
    output += '<h2>' + value.name +'</h2>'
    output += '<p>' + value.info + '</p>'
    output += '</a></li>';
});

$('#list_zoek_category').html(output).listview("refresh");

});
```

At this moment it displays "each" row in the data as a list item in the list.
But I want to display only the listitems where category == category.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make that work?

Comment: means you don't want to append or you want to hide the rows.

Comment: I don't want to append the rows to the list

Comment: just check if `value.category != 'category` do a return, Early exit is better, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if(value.category != 'category')
        return;  // So basically If value.category is not equal to 'category` do nothing, EARLY EXIT.
    output += '<li><a href="#">'
    output += '<img src="img/' + value.img + '.jpg">'
    output += '<h2>' + value.name +'</h2>'
    output += '<p>' + value.info + '</p>'
    output += '</a></li>';
});
```

Comment: Maybe you have an awnser to another question. If I click on a list-item  I want to generate a new list, with only listitems where the category is the same as the name of the list-item is just clicked. And if I click on an item in that list, I want to go to display the details. Is it better to generate a new list inside the page, or to go to a new page where I generate a new list?

Comment: better you ask a new question, because I don't know what is better, if you'll ask here only I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if(value.category == "category") {
        output += '<li><a href="#">'
        output += '<img src="img/' + value.img + '.jpg">'
        output += '<h2>' + value.name +'</h2>'
        output += '<p>' + value.info + '</p>'
        output += '</a></li>';
    }
});`

no tested but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a conditional test, first check if the object value has a category property then check if it matches your requirement:

```
var output = '';
$.each(data, function (index, value) {

    if (value.category && value.category==='category') {
       output += '<li><a href="#">'
       output += '<img src="img/' + value.img + '.jpg">'
       output += '<h2>' + value.name +'</h2>'
       output += '<p>' + value.info + '</p>'
       output += '</a></li>';
    }

});
```